# How to query MongoDB over HTTP API with “like”?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, http

I want to query data from MongoDB via the HTTP API in AngularJS. My code is like this:

```
$http.get('api/data', {user: user1});
```

How I can I change it, so that is searches for %user% like in SQL the LIKE operator? This both lines does not work:

```
$http.get('api/data', {user: /user1/});
$http.get('api/data', {user: {'$regex': 'user1'}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not depend on your webservice call. You are already sending regex.
You need to use it on your server, while finding the record in mongodb.

MongoDB has a builtin regex search:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

This should work for you:

```
db.users.find( { user: { $regex: your_regex_here } } )
```

Checkout the mongodb docs (from above link) for more options.

Comment: I don't get any results if I use your line in Angular. If I use it in PowerShell, it works.

Comment: It is not angular js code. It is meant to be for your server. Angular js is not firing requests on mongodb. It is firing `$http.get` which invokes the code on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've changed the code on server side (node.js) from $search to $regex. Now it works.